# Query for get how many times the number are displayed

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a help!

I have this table for documents (simplified version here):

```
       +----+-----+----+
Columns| v1 | v2  | v3 |
       +----+-----+----+
       | 1  | 5   | 11 |
       | 2  | 7   | 5  |
       | 10 | 11  | 18 |
       | 5  | 7   | 10 |
       +----+-----+----+
```

I'd to know how many times the number 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11 and 18 are displayed, independent of the column that they are inputted

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` to "unpivot" the data and then use aggregation:

```
select v, count(*)
from ((select v1 as v from t) union all
      (select v2 as v from t) union all
      (select v3 as v from t) union all
     ) t
group by v;
```

Comment: So fast.. just so fast.